# ADF: List of Values Update Multiple Fields

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, lov

I have an LOV added to my view object which updates 6 fields - done all through the LOV wizard in JDeveloper. It works perfectly fine when test running the application module - all fields update with the proper values after selecting a value from the LOV. However in my JSPX form, the only the field that gets updated is the one that the LOV is attached or is initiated on.

On my form, i only display 2 out of the 6 fields - the field which initiates the LOV and another editable field that the LOV  is supposed to update. The part where this gets interesting is that the 4 other fields in my view object that i dont put in my form, are updated successfully by the LOV! But the one additional editable field that i left in my form, isnt updated.

Why is that?

I could just write a method in my View object Row Implementation class to update that editable field manually, but i feel like theres something more straight forward via declarative approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I needed to update two settings on my 2nd field of the form.

1. Removed the default bindings on the "Required" attribute and set it to "false".
2. Set "ShowRequired" to true

After that, I saved my changes and re-ran my application and the field updated properly!

I hope others find this helpful!